# Go can not add accept and content-type headers at the same time

Tags: go

I am trying to write tests for a simple rest application in go. So I write something like this:

```
func TestMyTestFunc(t *testing.T) {
    var w = httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error creating request: %s", err.Error())
    }
    // req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    // req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    l.ServeHTTP(w, req)  // l is defined somewhere above
    // check for w.Code, w.Body
}
```

This works perfectly fine. Now I would like to add headers. So I add the commented header part and end up with:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

and the error is on this line: `l.ServeHTTP(w, req)`.

Interesting part, that if I set only `Content-Type` or `Accept`, the test runs, but if I set both, it fails. What's wrong?

P.S. I also tried to use `req.Header.Set`, but with no difference.
Here is an stub for my handler:

```
func (l myHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // check for validity
    if !valid {
       http.Error(w, "Invalid Accept", http.StatusBadRequest)
       return
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
    return
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Can you post the handler.

Comment: @yene thanks for looking into the problem. Added a handler, but I am not sure how exactly I could have screwed up the handler, that the compilation process fails only when both headers are set.

Comment: I think it fails because the server responds an error which is not handled. Try adding more error reporting and check the server logs.

Comment: I also think the problem is in the missing code of the handler. Would it be possible that somewhere in your ServeHTTP function you are checking the `Content-Type` or `Accept` header and when they are set to `application/json` you are attempting to parse the request body which is nil, therefore the panic? But I guess this is just a shot in the dark and I doubt that's what's really happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think error in your http server/handler implementation. I tried to reproduce it and it worked.

You can see here:
http://play.golang.org/p/n1YBl3OpbN

Comment: thanks for taking a look and even giving the working example.